# Add class to another div after button is clicked

Tags: javascript, css, html, transform

Right now i have my content to fade in when it reach viewport with transform:translate and opacity.

On my portfolio site i also have it but when i use my filter menu to sort through my images its acting weird because the filter menu is adding a class that has transform:scale;

So i made some simple JS that removes the content fade effect when the buttons are clicked but i would like to add it back AFTER the button is clicked to continue the fade effect if content is more than viewport.

Current JS to remove class:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
  $( ".btn" ).click(function() {
   $( ".items" ).removeClass( "move" );
  });
});
```

Comment: Can you also post your html and css, please?

Comment: @doutriforce Its kinda long tho.. I just need a JS code that remove a class on CLICK and then after its clicked it adds the class back. 

(haveclass - click - removeclass - delay 0.1s then adds back the class.

Comment: You already have a code that removes a class on `.click()`...to add it back with a delay, just run `.addClass('[class]')` inside `window.setTimeout()`.

Comment: @doutriforce So you mean like this???

 $( document ).ready(function() {
        $( ".btn" ).click(function() {
            $( ".items" ).removeClass( "move" );}
          else(  {setTimeout(function(){ .items('move'); }, 3000);
        })
    )});

Comment: No, your syntax is incorrect. Take a look at my answer.

Comment: Oh i see! It really helped alot to understand some JS.. I am really new at it.. But the transform i want to add after clicked does not work anyway with your code..

Comment: No problem. I think you could do it using css only though. But it's hard to tell, since there's not much information about what you're doing besides that snippet.  Let me know if it works out for you.

Comment: I have taken a look into your page. Why are you adding `triggeredCSS3-portfix` to every content div? Even the ones on another tab.

Comment: when i add the class "move" it added the class triggeredCSS3-portfix. The class does this : .move.triggeredCSS3-portfix     {transform :translate(0) !important; opacity: 1 !important; } Its what is making the fade in effect

Comment: I know that. But what i saw was that it won't `fadeIn` elements that already have the class `triggeredCSS3-portfix`. That's why the others are not fading in anymore. Cause the page is also applying this class to the elements of the other tab.

Comment: But it should still work? Before i posted this post i found out that if i delete this these classes, it would work like i want it to.

 `.tile {
 -webkit-transform: scale(0);
 transform: scale(0);
 -webkit-transition: all 350ms ease-in-out;
 transition: all 350ms ease-in-out;
}

.scale-anm {
 transform: scale(1);
}`

Comment: I have updated my answer.

Comment: Thanks for you time and your awesome code, but can not get it to work still.. 
I think i will contact my teacher tomorrow and ask if he can explain why my code isnt working. 
Thanks a lot dude ! :)

Comment: No problem, man. What's happening though? I have tested on your own site, and it worked fine.

Comment: Did you only add that JS and then it worked? 
I tried to add the JS and change around on the classes. Wont work :(

Comment: Yes. And by adding the classes i told you in the div's. I've uptaded my answer again with pictures to show you what i've done.

Comment: Okay. I have to look at it in the morning, its really late here. 
I post a comment how it would work. Thanks a alot again. :)

Comment: Alright, bro. No problem.

Comment: @doutriforce Okay fresh eyes made it more clear! Now i got it to work fine but i have to fix, that when i click the filter menu, they fade out and then fade in when scroll. Everything thats in viewport dont need to fade out. :-)